# is it easy to adapt the Actionscript so that you can get multiple flips?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

it’s a little sketchy on how to implement it in Flash.
    Is it easy to adapt the Actionscript so that you can get **multiple flips?** i.e., so that you can flip the card several times and get a different image each time?

Here is the code for two times flip and implement this. now i plan to move little bit forward to implement to flip the card several times.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }

        private function init(evt:Event=null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

            setClip();
        }

        private function setClip():void
        {
            clip_mc.z=300;
            clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=false;
            clip_mc.getChildAt(0).rotationY=180;
            clip_mc.mouseChildren=false;
            clip_mc.buttonMode=true;
            clip_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClipDown);
        }

        private function onClipDown(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            evt.target.mouseEnabled=false;

            var arrive:Number;
            if(clip_mc.rotationY > 89)
                arrive=0;
            else
                arrive=180;

            var my_tween=new TimelineLite();
            my_tween.insert(TweenLite.to(clip_mc,0.5,{z:200,ease:Back.easeOut }));
            my_tween.insert(TweenLite.to(clip_mc,1.5,{rotationY:arrive,ease:Strong.easeInOut,onUpdate:setClipSide,onUpdateParams:[clip_mc]}));
            my_tween.insert(TweenLite.to(clip_mc,0.5,{z:300,ease:Back.easeIn,onComplete:done}),0.75);
        }

        private function setClipSide(clip_mc)
        {
            if(clip_mc.rotationY > 89)
            {
                clip_mc.getChildAt(1).visible=false;
                clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=true;
            }
            else
            {
                clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=false;
                clip_mc.getChildAt(1).visible=true;
            }
        }

        private function done():void
        {
            clip_mc.mouseEnabled=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible.  Your question is "is it easy?" Well that depends on the programmer.  For good programmers yes that is very easy.  Specify what you have tried, and what exactly you are having trouble with instead of just asking us to do it for you.... If you need a push in the right direction, try expanding your setClipSide to more if statements with more children that are different images.... Just expand upon what you've got already.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is quiet possible your almost there, the way how you organizing the flips you can keep repeating that structure

```
   private function setClipSide(clip_mc)
    {
        if(clip_mc.rotationY > 89 && clip_mc.rotationY<280) // i added
        {
            clip_mc.getChildAt(1).visible=false;
            clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=true;
        }
        else
        {
            clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=false;
            clip_mc.getChildAt(1).visible=true;
        }
    }
```

What you will want to do is replace these lines below with variables, or functions or a formula

```
            clip_mc.getChildAt(1).visible=false;// here you have only limited yourself
            clip_mc.getChildAt(0).visible=true;//
```

So in that area you could either add a function to randomly generate card value, either from a variable or simply make a RNG out of the total lenght of your array[]-1 if thats how your images or values are stored.

heres an example of a slot machine i had made how all the movieclips are added to thier place depending on my number genenerator, except my RNG is PHP and then passed through to flash http://www.gamezslave.net/game/Slots.html let me know how you go.